# How do you align table headers and content using CSS in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, flexbox

I asked this question before but worded it totally wrong so I'll try again.

I have a CSS issue with a landing page I'm building on Vue.js.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir3sd.jpg)

I'm trying to align the table headers with the the table content. Anyone know the best way to do this - I'm been trying for 2 hours without getting anywhere.

Edit: I don't have admin privileges to add people to the project but would be more than happy to send the files via email, if you want to take a look...

Comment: There are so many ways to do it, but without visibility on your code it would be very difficult to propose a solution ... guyaristide@gmail.com is my email address

Comment: @AristideGuyEmmanuelKouakou Thanks - just emailed you with the code attached.

Comment: Do you try to set border-spacing?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't do anything

Comment: Please attach the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @Lars I don't have the privileges to grant access, but if you give me your email, I can send the code to you...

Answer (score 0):

Did you have used text-align ?

simple solution if do You want text-left, text-right or text-center in table column then add inline css otherwise external css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }
        .text-left {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .text-center {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .text-right {
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">Text Left Head</th>
                <th class="text-center">Text center Head</th>
                <th class="text-right">Text Right Head</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left">Text Left Body</td>
                <td class="text-center">Text center Body</td>
                <td class="text-right">Text Right Body</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The table has has its own component. So there's a Table Header, Table Row component